# Making the position of elements on the responsive view match the print preview in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, printing

I would really appreciate any help getting over this hurdle on developing my project. Thank you in advance for any solid reads or help i can get.

I'm creating a printable art app that simply has a menu of images and a blank <div> that's acts like a piece of paper. When you click on an image it gets added to the page and is draggable and resizable.

**I have an issue with placement on the view and placement on the print preview. They do not match.**

**Desired effect:**
**I would like to have a responsive view of the page while maintaining exact positioning of dragged elements on the print**

[image: Picture of the UI with image on page]

[image: Picture of the print preview]

This is the Page.js file with list of images that are inside a Draggable component.

```
return(
  <div id="printPage" className="page">
    {images.map((image) => (
      <Draggable className="dragContainer">
        <img
          key={image.key}
          className="artImages"
          src={image.url}
        />
      </Draggable>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

This is the CSS for that component

```
.page {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 296mm;
  transform: scale(0.75, .5);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}

.dragContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
  will-change: transform;
  background: none;
  border: 5px solid white;
  cursor: grab;
  touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.artImages {
  will-change: transform;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

@media print {
  .page {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    margin: 0;
    width: initial;
    height: initial;
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are already some packages available, which would enormously simplify pdf generation. I would suggest to try out react-pdf: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf

Comment: Can you create a work online snippet?